# Nginx: Mapping WordPress URLs to new static website

Tags: python, wordpress, nginx, nikola

I am currently moving my blog from a WordPress site that used the URL scheme:

```
http://www.domainname.com/<YEAR>/<MONTH>/<ARTICLE_SLUG>
```

To a static blog site built with [Nikola](http://getnikola.com/) that uses the following URL scheme:

```
http://www.domainname.com/posts/<ARTICLE_SLUG>
```

The original WordPress scheme had built a little bit of Google juice over the years and I would like keep harnessing that. I use Nginx as my web server. Is there a simple way for Nginx to map all the old URLs to the new URLs via configuration. I was thinking that the [`ngx_http_map_module` Nginx Module](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_map_module.html) is the most likely candidate, but I wanted to get a second opinion.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Should work.  Just put a location block in your server config similar to this

```
location ~ "^/[\d]{4}/[\d]{2}/(.*)$"   {return 301 $scheme://$host/posts/$1;}
```